# zio, custom Assertion renderer for current value

Tags: customization, assertion, zio

We have a custom `zio.test.Assertion` that wrap [json-path-assert](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/tree/master/json-path-assert):

```
  def isJson(matching: org.hamcrest.Matcher[_ >: ReadContext]): Assertion[HttpEntity] = {
    def test(entity: => HttpEntity): Boolean = {
      // Removed for brevity
    }
    Assertion.assertion[HttpEntity]("isJson")(param(matching))(test)
  }
```

We are quite happy with it but the failure message is far to be obvious:

> `response.body` = Strict(ByteString(121, 32, 95, 111, 10, 108, 113, 35, 50, 90, 124, 23, 112, 111, 112, 31, 48, 24, 46, 31, 111, 22, 111, 25, 93, 52, 41, 54, 59, 90, 100, 43, 42, 51, 75, 14, 41, 54, 40, 65, 34, 42, 99, 88, 100, 54, 34, 25, 33, 89, 41, 40, 54, 52, 44, 40, 31, 101, 112, 105, 91, 10, 35, 125, 79, 106, 95, 11, 11, 32, 85, 13, 43, 104, 111)... and [661] more,Some(application/json)) did not satisfy isJson(with json path "$['store']['name']")

I would like to print the Json string decoded from those bytes but I do not see how to do that.

How can we customize the messages of a custom `zio.test.Assertion`?

Thanks

Comment: would you consider mapping the error in the business logic?

Comment: Do you mean, using code in addition to the assertion itself? If that's the case, no. We would like to have one assertion that works out-of-the-box, without anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The `param(matching)` means that you are using the `toString` method of `matching` to render the the input of the assertion.

You can pass the decoded json string instead to have that display. For example (assuming your json is UTF-8 encoded):

```scala
 Assertion.assertion[HttpEntity.Strict]("isJson")
     (param(matching.data.decodeString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))(test)
```

That particular example only works on `HttpEntity.Strict` but can be generalized to `HttpEntity` if you access the entity contents with `.dataStream`